# React JS Dispatch Not Defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

So I'm trying to send the information from a login form to an action, then set the app's state's userLogged property to true if the login procedure is successful.

```
    renderForm() {
        return (
            <Form
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                    // call the login function.
                    // if called with this.props.login, I get the error 
                    // 'cannot read `type` of undefined'
                    login(values.email, values.password);
                }}
                validate={({ email, password }) => {
                    // validation rules
                }}>
                {({submitForm}) => {
                    return (
                        <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                            // form fields
                        </form>
                    );
                }}
            </Form>
        );
    }
```

Now, after the declaration of the component I have the following:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ login }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { userLogged: state.userLogged.userLogged };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginComponent);
```

The action receives the information, calls the API, but does not get to the reducer, and the app gives the 'dispatch not defined' error, even though the store, middleware and bindActionCreators have already been imported.

```
export function login(email, password) {
    const request = axios({
        headers: { 
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        url: `${ROOT_URL}login/login`,
        params: {
            email,
            password
        }
    })
    .then((data) => dispatch(dispatchLogin(data)));
}

function dispatchLogin(data) {
    return {
        type: 'USER_LOGIN',
        payload: data
    };
}
```

The reducer should retrieve the action's type and act edit the app's state.

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'USER_LOGIN': {
            console.log(action.payload.data);
            state.userLogged = action.payload.data.status;
            return { ...state }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux actions are synchronous by default, you have to use a middleware like redux-thunk for asynchronous actions: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Example (untested):

```
export function login(email, password) {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        let data = await axios({
            headers: { 
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'post',
            url: `${ROOT_URL}login/login`,
            params: {
                email,
                password
            }
        });
        dispatch(dispatchLogin(data));
    };
}
```